# Induction problem

Tags: sequences-and-series, solution-verification, induction

I need to prove using induction that
$$
\frac{1}{1\cdot 2}+\frac{1}{2\cdot 3} + \cdots +\frac{1}{n(n+1)} >\frac{9n-1}{10(n+1)} \ ,\ for \ \ n \in \mathbb{N}
$$
I know how to prove it without induction, but when I try using induction I get 0>0 which is false.

[image: my proof]

Comment: Not really an answer, but: You can actually prove by induction that the left side is exactly equal to $1-\frac1{n+1}.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\frac{9k-1}{10(k+1)}+\frac{1}{(k+1)(k+2)}=\frac{9k+8}{10(k+2)}$, the inductive step is simple enough. Your problem was an incorrect guess as to how to "prove it backwards". We all prove things backwards: we work out what would be enough to finish the step. In your case, instead of guessing the above $=$, you tried a $>$, which doesn't work.

Comment: aww you are right!!
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that the RHS of your induction step should say only $$\frac{9(k+1) - 1}{10(k+2)}$$ because that is the substitution you get from the RHS of the original statement with $n=k+1$, whereas what you have is the RHS with $n=k$ and then also the next term of the series, but the series was from the LHS to begin with.

Comment: my proof is not like that, I'm starting in one side and I want to get to the other. so I starter with the sum on the left side and I'm trying to ,make it smaller, after that I used algebra to prove the last inequality.